# python help - conditional math operation on arrays

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to learn python - but new to OOP. I'd like to make the functions fA, fB, fC operate on the whole r-theta space at once, instead of one point at a time. My problem is the conditional (r<=1). The code below is quite ugly (!) but it works.

How can I make this more pythonesque?  Thanks!

(in this simplified example, note the math for (r>1) diverges when r goes to zero)

```
from math import pi, sin, cos, exp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fA(rr,th,a,b,c):
    if (rr<=1):
        fx = a * sin(th)
        fy = b * rr * cos(th)
        fz = c * rr
    else:
        fx = (a / rr) * sin(th)
        fy = (b / rr) * cos(th)
        fz = (c / rr)
    return(fx,fy,fz)

def fB(rr,th,a,b,c):
    if (rr<=1):
        fx = b * sin(2.*th)
        fy = a * rr * cos(2.*th)
        fz = c * rr
    else:
        fx = (b / rr) * sin(2.*th)
        fy = (a / rr) * cos(2.*th)
        fz = c
    return(fx,fy,fz)

def fC(rr,th,a,b,c):
    if (rr<=1):
        fx = exp(rr - 1.) * cos(th)
        fy = exp(rr - 1.) * sin(th)
        fz = c 
    else:
        fx = exp(1. - rr) * cos(th)
        fy = exp(1. - rr) * sin(th)
        fz = c / rr
    return(fx,fy,fz)


nx = 101
ny = 101
dx = 4. / (nx-1)
dy = 4. / (ny-1)

X = np.zeros((ny,nx))
Y = np.zeros((ny,nx))

for ix in range(nx):
    for iy in range(ny):
        X[iy,ix] = dx*(ix - (nx-1)/2)
        Y[iy,ix] = dy*(iy - (ny-1)/2)

r = np.sqrt(X**2. + Y**2.)
theta = np.arctan2(Y,X)

Ax = np.zeros((ny,nx))
Ay = np.zeros((ny,nx))
Az = np.zeros((ny,nx))

Bx = np.zeros((ny,nx))
By = np.zeros((ny,nx))
Bz = np.zeros((ny,nx))

Cx = np.zeros((ny,nx))
Cy = np.zeros((ny,nx))
Cz = np.zeros((ny,nx))


for ix in range (nx):
    for iy in range(ny):
        Ax[iy,ix], Ay[iy,ix], Az[iy,ix] = fA(r[iy,ix], theta[iy,ix], 1.0, 1.0, 1.5)
        Bx[iy,ix], By[iy,ix], Bz[iy,ix] = fB(r[iy,ix], theta[iy,ix], 1.5, 0.8, 1.0)
        Cx[iy,ix], Cy[iy,ix], Cz[iy,ix] = fC(r[iy,ix], theta[iy,ix], 0.9, 1.1, 1.2)

plt.figure()

plt.subplot(3,3,1)
plt.imshow(Ax)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Ax')

plt.subplot(3,3,2)
plt.imshow(Ay)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Ay')

plt.subplot(3,3,3)
plt.imshow(Az)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Az')


plt.subplot(3,3,4)
plt.imshow(Bx)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Bx')

plt.subplot(3,3,5)
plt.imshow(By)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('By')

plt.subplot(3,3,6)
plt.imshow(Bz)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Bz')


plt.subplot(3,3,7)
plt.imshow(Cx)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Cx')

plt.subplot(3,3,8)
plt.imshow(Cy)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Cy')

plt.subplot(3,3,9)
plt.imshow(Cz)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Cz')

plt.show()
```

Comment: i dont think you can use like  X[iy,ix]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @mdurant said `np.where` and `np.meshgrid` will be useful.  Here, let me reorganize your code and provide another way to avoid Python looping by using [numpy advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean):

```py
import sys
from math import pi, sin, cos, exp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def _generate_coordinate(nx, ny):
    """
    Generate coordinate data points in a function to prevent namespace
    pollution.
    """
    dx = 4. / (nx-1)
    dy = 4. / (ny-1)
    X = np.zeros((ny,nx))
    Y = np.zeros((ny,nx))
    for ix in range(nx):
        for iy in range(ny):
            X[iy,ix] = dx*(ix - (nx-1)/2)
            Y[iy,ix] = dy*(iy - (ny-1)/2)
    return np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2), np.arctan2(Y,X)

nx = ny = 101
r, theta = _generate_coordinate(101, 101)


def calculate_numpy():
    # Helper methods for vector-based calculator.
    def fA(rr, th, a, b, c):
        # Calculate every value because mulplication doesn't give NaN.
        arrx = a * np.sin(th)
        arry = b * rr * np.cos(th)
        arrz = c * rr
        # Override value with a certain condition.
        slct = rr > 1
        rr = rr[slct]
        th = th[slct]
        arrx[slct] = a / rr * np.sin(th)
        arry[slct] = b / rr * np.cos(th)
        arrz[slct] = c / rr
        return arrx, arry, arrz
    def fB(rr, th, a, b, c):
        # Calculate every value because mulplication doesn't give NaN.
        arrx = b * np.sin(2.*th)
        arry = a * rr * np.cos(2.*th)
        arrz = c * rr
        # Override value with a certain condition.
        slct = rr > 1
        rr = rr[slct]
        th = th[slct]
        arrx[slct] = b / rr * np.sin(2.*th)
        arry[slct] = a / rr * np.cos(2.*th)
        arrz[slct] = c
        return arrx, arry, arrz
    def fC(rr,th,a,b,c):
        # Calculate every value because mulplication doesn't give NaN.
        arrx = np.exp(rr-1) * np.cos(th)
        arry = np.exp(rr-1) * np.sin(th)
        arrz = np.empty_like(rr)
        arrz.fill(c)
        # Override value with a certain condition.
        slct = rr > 1
        rr = rr[slct]
        th = th[slct]
        arrx[slct] = np.exp(1.-rr) * np.cos(th)
        arry[slct] = np.exp(1.-rr) * np.sin(th)
        arrz[slct] = c / rr
        return arrx, arry, arrz
    # Carry out calculation.
    Ax, Ay, Az = fA(r, theta, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5)
    Bx, By, Bz = fB(r, theta, 1.5, 0.8, 1.0)
    Cx, Cy, Cz = fC(r, theta, 0.9, 1.1, 1.2)
    return Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz


def calculate_loop():
    # Helper methods for loop calculator.
    def fA(rr,th,a,b,c):
        if (rr<=1):
            fx = a * sin(th)
            fy = b * rr * cos(th)
            fz = c * rr
        else:
            fx = (a / rr) * sin(th)
            fy = (b / rr) * cos(th)
            fz = (c / rr)
        return(fx,fy,fz)
    def fB(rr,th,a,b,c):
        if (rr<=1):
            fx = b * sin(2.*th)
            fy = a * rr * cos(2.*th)
            fz = c * rr
        else:
            fx = (b / rr) * sin(2.*th)
            fy = (a / rr) * cos(2.*th)
            fz = c
        return(fx,fy,fz)
    def fC(rr,th,a,b,c):
        if (rr<=1):
            fx = exp(rr - 1.) * cos(th)
            fy = exp(rr - 1.) * sin(th)
            fz = c 
        else:
            fx = exp(1. - rr) * cos(th)
            fy = exp(1. - rr) * sin(th)
            fz = c / rr
        return(fx,fy,fz)
    # Create buffer arrays for loops.
    Ax = np.zeros((ny,nx))
    Ay = np.zeros((ny,nx))
    Az = np.zeros((ny,nx))
    Bx = np.zeros((ny,nx))
    By = np.zeros((ny,nx))
    Bz = np.zeros((ny,nx))
    Cx = np.zeros((ny,nx))
    Cy = np.zeros((ny,nx))
    Cz = np.zeros((ny,nx))
    # Carry out calculation with Python loops.  This is slow.
    for ix in range (nx):
        for iy in range(ny):
            Ax[iy,ix], Ay[iy,ix], Az[iy,ix] = fA(r[iy,ix], theta[iy,ix], 1.0, 1.0, 1.5)
            Bx[iy,ix], By[iy,ix], Bz[iy,ix] = fB(r[iy,ix], theta[iy,ix], 1.5, 0.8, 1.0)
            Cx[iy,ix], Cy[iy,ix], Cz[iy,ix] = fC(r[iy,ix], theta[iy,ix], 0.9, 1.1, 1.2)
    return Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz


def main():
    calculate = globals()["calculate_" + sys.argv[1]]
    Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz = calculate()

    plt.figure()

    plt.subplot(3,3,1)
    plt.imshow(Ax)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Ax')

    plt.subplot(3,3,2)
    plt.imshow(Ay)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Ay')

    plt.subplot(3,3,3)
    plt.imshow(Az)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Az')


    plt.subplot(3,3,4)
    plt.imshow(Bx)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Bx')

    plt.subplot(3,3,5)
    plt.imshow(By)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('By')

    plt.subplot(3,3,6)
    plt.imshow(Bz)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Bz')


    plt.subplot(3,3,7)
    plt.imshow(Cx)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Cx')

    plt.subplot(3,3,8)
    plt.imshow(Cy)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Cy')

    plt.subplot(3,3,9)
    plt.imshow(Cz)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Cz')

    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The function `calculate_numpy()` is where I demonstrate the advanced indexing.  If you want to totally avoid duplicated calculation, you will need to create buffers like what you did in `calculate_loop()`.  But I would say in terms of runtime, the duplication calculation is OK.

Let's say the program is saved in a file `draw.py`.  We have both numpy ndarray and loop versions of the code, and can use `timeit` to benchmark them:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "import draw" "draw.calculate_loop()"
10 loops, best of 3: 95.2 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "import draw" "draw.calculate_numpy()"
100 loops, best of 3: 2.11 msec per loop
```

As you can see, the numpy version is 45 times faster than your loop version.  Most of the cases it's good enough.

Comment: OK, I will try it now... I get an error but I will try to find out why ...`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/../Solution_from_Stackoverflow.py", line 182, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/.../Solution_from_Stackoverflow.py", line 127, in main
    calculate = globals()["calculate_" + sys.argv[1]]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: In the command line run it with an argument like "python draw.py loop" or "python draw.py numpy".  The script will find the corresponding `calculate_{loop,numpy}()` for execution.  The timeit should be run in the command line as well.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing one of your relations at random, you can use numpy.where instead of the if... semantics:

```
fx = where( rr<=1, exp(rr - 1.) * cos(th), exp(1. - rr) * cos(th))
```

This effectively does if/else for a set of arrays rather than one at a time individual numbers. You would then be able to do Ax, Ay, Az = fA(...) without the looping.

X and Y you can make using meshgrid or mgrid.

To not evaluate all elements, you could use slice notation

```
fx = empty_like(rr)
fx[rr<=1] = exp(rr[rr<=1] - 1.) * cos(th[rr<=1])
fx[rr>1] = exp(1. - rr[rr>1]) * cos(th[rr>1]))
```

Comment: It seems both are evaluated first, without regard to the condition. I would like conditional evaluation to save time and avoid errors

Comment: e.g.    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> np.where( 2>1, 1., 0.)
    array(1.0)
    >>> np.where( 2>1, 1., 1./0.)

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
        np.where( 2>1, 1., 1./0.)
    ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Comment: `    >>> import numpy as np'
'    >>> np.where( 2>1, 1., 0.)'
'    array(1.0)'
'    >>> np.where( 2>1, 1., 1./0.)'
' '
'    Traceback (most recent call last):'
'      File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>'
'        np.where( 2>1, 1., 1./0.)'
'    ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero'

Comment: You are correct about that, but it is the most concise in expressing what you mean, and will still be faster than looping. I can post an alternative, if you wish.

Comment: I think generating 100,000 divide by zero (and other divergence) errors and 50% redundant unused evaluations will not be a good thing. The real math is pretty long and has various special function calls to SciPy. If you could suggest another approach that would be great, thanks!